# Meaning of 'patchy at best'?

Tags: meaning, phrases

> Its social web services initiatives have been **patchy at best**, so Google hasn't managed to muscle in on Facebook or Twitter like it has with Microsoft and Yahoo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Patchy* is to describe their initiatives as only covering some small parts of what it could be covering.

*At best* is to imply that the description *patchy* is perhaps generous.

Answer (score 1):

The writer probably means to say that the quality of Google social web services has been inconsistent, tending to poor.

I doubt they are referring to coverage (another possible interpretation of *patchy*) since by that measure any service provider, including Facebook and Twitter, would also fall short, making the comparison pointless.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=patch&searchmode=none) has *patchy* as derived from the second definition of patch below.

> **patch (1)** 
>   "piece of cloth used to mend another material," late 14c., of obscure origin, perhaps a variant of *pece, pieche*, from O.N.Fr. *pieche* (see piece), or from an unrecorded O.E. word. The verb is mid-15c., from the noun; electronics sense of "to connect temporarily" is attested from 1923. Phrase *not a patch* on "nowhere near as good as" is from 1860.
>
> **patch (2)** 
>   "fool, clown," 1540s, perhaps from It. *pazzo* "fool," which is possibly from O.H.G. *barzjan* "to rave." Form perhaps influenced by folk etymology derivation from patch (1), on notion of a fool's patched garb. But Buck says *pazzo* is originally euphemistic, and from L. *patiens* "suffering," in medical use, "the patient."
>
> **patchy** 
>   1798, from patch + -y (2).

And *NOAD* on the phrase *at best* (coincidentally using *patchy* as well):

> **at best** taking the most optimistic or favorable view : *signs of recovery are patchy at best.*

It's sometimes used in parallel with *at worst*:

> **at worst** (or **the worst**) in the most serious case : *at worst the injury could mean months in the hospital*. • under the most unfavorable interpretation : *the cabinet's reaction to the crisis was at best ineffective and at worst irresponsible.*